# New User to Realm Modal

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, realm

I currently try to use realm instead of core data, and I am using swift. I noticed that the realm plugin in xcode generates objC style modal. Is it okay for me just creating a new swift file and import Realm instead of using realm plugin? Also, I use the default way to write data into my Realm Modal

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(myFirstPost)
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

How to use the Realm Browser to see my current local database. I cannot find the .realm file in my xcode project file folder. Where did I store the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, create a new swift file and make sure to import Realm.

[Here is a good thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/realm-cocoa/F1Y-KNBQM2g) on how to find your .realm file while using the simulator.

Comment: Thx! However, the link seems not working. Could you update the link?

Comment: Sorry about that, can you check now?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to terminal and type

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/deploy/Scripts/install.sh | sh
   ```
2. Restart xcode --> window --> package Manager --> search for Realm and install.
3. Import Realm framework in General --> Embedded libraries
4. Now create new file in xcode.
5. Click realm plugin that appears in IOS template.
6. Now you can choose the language as swift.

Answer (score 0):

To find your realm database put this in your viewDidLoad():

```
print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!)
```